# WatchKit table with section header and accessory view

Tags: tableview, watchkit, apple-watch

I would like to make a table in my WatchKit app that looks like this:

[image]

So I want to have a section header (WRIST), and then a table with a custom number of rows where the first and the last have rounded edges, and I want to be able to select one of them.

As far as I saw this cannot be done out-of-the-box. Am I missing something? Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done, but the pattern is not the same as it is in the iPhone. You will need to make 3 separate cell templates. The top one will contain your header and the cell text with rounded corners on the top. The second would contain just the cell text data and square corders. The third would contain the cell text and have rounded corners at the bottom.

Note that you will need to use a background image to get a cell to have rounded corners on one side and edges on the other.

Comment: But how do I make rounded corners just on top, or just on bottom? Do I have to have background images for this?

Comment: Yes, you will need need to use a background image to get only one side of the group to have rounded corners.

Comment: Please update your answer with this, so that I can accept it. And thanks!